# Keep receiving javax.mail.Session$1: method <init>()V not found when trying to send an email using Springboot + mvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

This is the code tht generates the error:

```
import com.cisco.s3.util.Logging;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class EmailController {

    private static final Logger log = Logging.getLogger(EmailController.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    @RequestMapping("/simpleemail")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        try {
            sendEmail();
            return "Email Sent!";
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            return "Error in sending email: " + ex;
        }
    }

    private void sendEmail() throws Exception{
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();

        // Enable the multipart flag!
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);

        helper.setTo("arterome@cisco.com");
        helper.setFrom("security-orchestration@cisco.com");
        helper.setText("How are you?");
        helper.setSubject("Hi");

        ClassPathResource file = new ClassPathResource("cat.jpg");
        helper.addAttachment("eagle.jpg", file);

        sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

And the error is quite long, let me add a piece of it:

````
```
[ERROR] 2019-05-22 09:14:17 @ org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.mail.Session$1: method <init>()V not found] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.mail.Session$1: method <init>()V not found
    at javax.mail.Session.<clinit>(Session.java:240) ~[soar-toolbox-2.0.0-beta.31.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.getSession(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:161) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:339) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at com.cisco.s3.controller.EmailController.sendEmail(EmailController.java:44) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.cisco.s3.controller.EmailController.home(EmailController.java:36) ~[classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ```
````

I've been reading a lot regarding this same project and it seemd to be a compatibility issue somewhere but I just have not been able to track it.

I am using gradle for dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.cisco.s3:soar-toolbox:2.0.0-beta.31'
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap'
    compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.10.2'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

I have been trying to resolve this issue since a week ago with zero success.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Check the transitive dependencies and make sure two different versions of JavaMail aren't being pulled in.  Also check that you don't have the GNU Classpath version of JavaMail installed on your Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` indicates that `com.cisco.s3:soar-toolbox:2.0.0-beta.31` dependency is not compatible with `javax.mail` version that you are running.

`soar-toolbox` looks proprietary, so you have to refer to the documentation provided by Cisco to see which Java and Java EE versions are supported.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the exact problem is but I would imagine it is that you have not setup a mailing account with the javax.mail.Session object.  docs can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html

You should be able to update /src/main/resources/application.properties with properties like:

- spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
- spring.mail.port=587
- spring.mail.username=YOUR_EMAIL
- spring.mail.password=YOUR_EMAIL_PASS
- spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
- spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

With this, you will also need to make sure your email provider (gmail in the above case) is setup as, I believe it is called - 'a service email'

Some improvements I would also advise:

1. @Controllers should also be annotated with @RequestMapping at the class level
2. If this is for an API - indicated by @ResponseBody shown on one of your @RequestMappings, I would advise switching the class to @RestController and removing @ResponseBody

Comment: I did a couple of changes but result seems to be the same, I am using simpleMailMessage now, but error is exactly the same, which is weird because I am not using `javax.mail.Session`

Comment: I would reccomend taking off the soar-toolbox dependency - see what happens and go from there.